# Deduce global estimate from scaling-invariant local estimate

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis

Let $(M,g)$ be a non-compact Riemannian manifold, with finite volume (or compactly exhausted, or any nice condition you would like, *except for* compactness). Suppose I have a tensor $T$ on $M$ of which I have "good" estimate locally, and I would like to have a global estimate of $T$. However, since $M$ is non-compact and I'm not allowed to take a finite cover, I have to avoid the following scenario: the "good" local estimate is only obtained because I can arbitrarily shrink the neighborhood. Hence some scaling-invariance is needed for the local estimate. A model would be the following

**Question**: Let $(M,g)$ be a non-compact Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$, with finite volume. If $T$ is a $q$-form on $M$, and there is a fixed number $H$ such that for every $x\in M$,
$$
\sigma^{q-n}\int_{B_{\sigma}(x)}|T|\mathrm{vol}_g<H
$$
for sufficiently small $\sigma$, where $B_{\sigma}(x)$ is the geodesic ball of radius $\sigma$ centered at $x$. Can one deduce
$$
\int_M|T|\mathrm{vol}_g<C_{M,H}
$$
from the local estimate? (If yes, how? If no, what should be the correct statement?)

**Better**: Can the scaling-invariant local estimate be phrased in a way that only involves "neighborhoods," instead of "radius of geodesic balls?" (And still yielding a global estimate, of course.)

Comment: Should it be $|T|^2$?

Comment: Ah, yes! I changed the power (2q-n) to (q-n). Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried testing your conjecture for functions and vectors (in particular, constant ones) on $R^n$?

Comment: Even for a bounded domain $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, and a function $f$ defined on $U$, the answer doesn't seem obvious to me. For constant functions $f=K$, the statement is true- the local estimate gives a bound on $K$, so the global estimate is given by a constant depending on $K$ and the volume of $U$.

Comment: Isn't the second integral unbounded if the function is constant?

Comment: Why? $M$ is supposed to have finite volume, and the constant $C_{M,H}$ depends on both $M$ and $H$.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I missed that.

Comment: No problem- thank you for the comments!

Comment: So it suffices to prove an $L^\infty$ bound on the tensor.

Comment: Obviously, I haven't thought about this carefully (even though I once knew this stuff cold), but I believe that the only possible issue is whether the tensor blows up at a point or not. What are your assumptions about $T$?

Comment: The reason I'm interested in this is that I have a curvature tensor $F$ whose $L^p$ norm blows up at finitely many points $Z$ of a compact manifold $X$, but I have good local estimates for the $L^p$ norm of $F$ away from these points. However, I would like to have a bound on the $L^p$ norm of $F$ over the entire $X-Z$. What would be your strategy to obtain this bound? I don't have extra assumptions on $F$, and an $L^{\infty}$ bound seems too strong.

Comment: If all you have is a scale invariant estimate away from the points, then there's no way to get a global bound. You should be able to construct a counterexample (use a function) that blows up at one of the points and does not have a finite $L^p$ bound. Just use whatever blow-up rate (as a function of distance to the point) that gives the scale-invariant integral bound you stated.